# Which is the Matrix4x4 format from ARCore NDK Pose?

Tags: c++, matrix, android-ndk, augmented-reality, arcore

When using this function in **NDK**:

```
void ArPose_getMatrix(
    const ArSession *session,
    const ArPose *pose,
    float *out_matrix_col_major_4x4
)
```

I get a `Pointer to an array of 16 floats, to be filled with a column-major homogenous transformation matrix, as used by OpenGL.`

But I don't know if this matrix is:

```
x.x, x.y, x.z, 0
y.x, y.y, y.z, 0
z.x, z.y, z.z, 0
t.x, t.y, t.z, 1
```

or

```
x.x, x.y, x.z, x.t
y.x, y.y, y.z, y.t
z.x, z.y, z.z, z.t
  0,   0,   0,   1
```

I only know the order to read: `x.x, y.x, z.x ...` since is column-major.

**How do I know the right format?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of components in ARCore `*out_matrix_col_major_4x4` is the same as in [OpenGL Matrices](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/):

**ARCore documentation [says about it obviously](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/c/group/pose)**:

> `out_matrix_col_major_4x4` is a Pointer to an array of 16 floats, to be filled with a column-major homogenous transformation matrix, as used by OpenGL.

[image]

The first three elements in the **rightmost column** [0,0,0,1] are for translation along `x`,`y`,`z` axis:

[image]

The first three elements in the **lowest row** [0,0,0,1] in this 4x4 matrix are for affine mapping. So, the last row of the 4x4 matrix has to be respected when you're applying transformations after a projection.

> Term **Column-Major** means: the elements of this matrix are gettable and settable using **columns' order**. Thus, translate `x`, `y`, `z` elements are located in the rightmost fourth column.